# Mockito instance of inner class

Tags: java, mockito, inner-classes

```
simpleJDBCCall.returningResultSet("test", new RowMapper<SomeObject> {
  
@Override
public SomeObject mapRow(Resultset r, int i) throws sqlexception {

//-----some code----
return someObject;

}

}
```

I want to execute the lines written inside the MapRow method using mockito

Comment: wdym `execute the lines written inside the MapRow method using mockito` ? mokito 'replace' your method behavior

Comment: By that I meant , to cover the lines as it reflects in sonarQube.

Comment: it' not clear, pls edit with more details and context ! first of all, why would you want to mock a RowMapper?

Comment: I think that's all the info I can give

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mockito is used to stub methods, not really to *execute* methods. But it's still possible: you can stub your method with a [dynamic `Answer`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#answer_stubs) to call the method of the passed instance of the [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

```
final SimpleJdbcCall simpleJDBCCall = Mockito.mock(…);
when(simpleJDBCCall.returningResultSet(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any())).
    .thenAnswer(i -> {
      final RowMapper<SomeObject> rowMapper = i.getArgument(1);
      rowMapper.mapRow(…, …); // pass your desired ResultSet and integer
    });
```

Calling now `returningResultSet` on your mock instance will immediately invoke the `mapRow` method on your second argument, passing any values that you specify.

Note however what the [official docs](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#answer_stubs) say about stubbing this way:

> Yet another controversial feature which was not included in Mockito originally. We recommend simply stubbing with `thenReturn()` or `thenThrow()`, which should be enough to test/test-drive any clean and simple code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, The rowMapper object getting from arguments is coming as null.

Comment: @H1312 not sure what you mean. `i.getArguments(1)` will return the argument as passed to the method. If null was passed, you get null, otherwise you get non-null.

Comment: now working thanks , was returning a string instead of simplejdbccall mock.